# How I can send a string to a Bluetooth Device in Delphi Android?

Tags: android, delphi, io, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have a Question to Delphi and Bluetooth. I use the JNI for Bluetooth Connection and my Problem is it to send a string to th printer. I try the code from ---

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vesPd5WvykA

and this work but I don't get a text :P

I create a class AndroidBluetooth that I use in my Project. For this Class I create a function (PrintText) this get a string parameter and must print the string on the printer.

**Here my code:**

```
 {Funktion: Druckt einen String auf einem Bluetooth Gerät}
      function TAndroidBluetooth.PrintText(text : string) : string;
     var
    i:integer;
    s:string;
  begin

      s:='$'+text+#13;
      for i:=0 to pred(length(s)) do ostream.write(ord(s[i])); // einmal senden mit 255 am anfang


  end;
```

**Here I create the connection**

```
    {Funktion: Stellt eine Verbindung zu einem Bluetooth Gerät her}
      function TAndroidBluetooth.CreateConnectionToBluetoothDevice(device : TListViewItem) : string;
      begin
         Toast('Selected '+device.Text);
      targetMAC:=device.Detail;
      if trim(targetMAC)='' then exit;

      Adapter:=TJBluetoothAdapter.JavaClass.getDefaultAdapter;
      remoteDevice:=Adapter.getRemoteDevice(stringtojstring(targetMAC));
      Toast('Connecting to '+device.Text+' ('+device.Detail+')');

      devicename := device.Text;

      sock:=remoteDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uid);

      try sock.connect;  
      except Toast('Could not create service record!'); //<--- that is the message if i try it
      end;
      if not sock.isConnected then
      begin
        Toast('Failed to connect to '+targetMAC+'! Try again...');
        exit;
      end;
      Toast('Connected!');

      ostream:=sock.getOutputStream;
      istream:=sock.getInputStream;

      Application.ProcessMessages;
  ostream.write(ord(255)); //
  ostream.write(ord(255)); // get device id   (nur Chitanda)
  sleep(200);

  len:=istream.available;
  if len=0 then exit;
  buffer:=TJavaArray<byte>.create(len);
  istream.read(buffer,0,len);
  s:='';
  for i:=0 to len-1 do s:=s+'0x'+inttohex(buffer[i],2)+', ';
  Toast(s);

      end;
```

The connection work but the print function don't work ...I get message 'Could not create service record!'

Comment: You're clearly getting an exception on connect. However because you are mishandling it you have no idea what the problem is. Replace your `Toast` method with an `On E:Exception Do` and interrogate the raised exception for the correct type and a more informative error message.

Comment: look @ my update ..in the print fuction i can print now ...but if the variable text is hello...the printer print hellohellohellohellohello..

Comment: how i can print only the text ?

Comment: I have no idea as you haven't shown the code that calls your function.

Comment: ok...I have found a answer in java but i must know ow i can do this in delphi---> IN JAVA: byte[] byteString = msg.getBytes(); outStream.write(byteString);   #######  IN Delphi: buffer:TJavaArray<byte> = text. ??? how I can convert astring in a system.byte that I can use this for the ostream.write method?